# Convert a dataframe to presence absence matrix

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a table which has unequal number of element in string format

```
File1 A  B  C
File2 A  B  D
File3 E  F
```

I want to convert into a format as follows

```
        A B C D E F
File1   1 1 1 0 0 0 
FIle2   1 1 0 1 0 0
File3   0 0 0 0 1 1
```

I tried to do it using reshape2 but was not successful.

Sample data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(V1 = c("File1", "File2", "File3"), 
                         V2 = c("A", "A", "E"), V3 = c("B", "B", "F"), 
                         V4 = c("C", "D", "")), 
                   .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "V1")
with(df2, table(V1, value))

#         value
# V1      A B C D E F
#   File1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#   File2 1 1 0 1 0 0
#   File3 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

A reasonably efficient approach is to use the (presently) non-exported `charMat` function from my "splitstackshape" package. Since it's not exported, you will have to use `:::` to access it.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cbind(mydata[1], splitstackshape:::charMat(
  split.default(mydata[-1], sequence(ncol(mydata)-1)), fill=0))
#      V1 V1 A B C D E F
# 1 File1  0 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 2 File2  0 1 1 0 1 0 0
# 3 File3  1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Under the hood, `charMat` makes use of matrix indexing to process everything pretty efficiently. Step-by-step, this is what `charMat` does.

```
X <- split.default(mydata[-1], sequence(ncol(mydata)-1))
len <- length(X)
vec <- unlist(X, use.names=FALSE)
lvl <- sort(unique(vec))
out <- matrix(0L, nrow = len, ncol = length(lvl), dimnames = list(NULL, lvl))
i.idx <- rep(seq.int(len), vapply(X, length, integer(1L)))
j.idx <- match(vec, lvl)
out[cbind(i.idx, j.idx)] <- 1
out
#        A B C D E F
# [1,] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
# [2,] 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
# [3,] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

That looks like a mouthful, but it is actually quite a fast operation, made faster by using the `charMat` function :-)

---

#### Update: Benchmarks

The following benchmarks test Henrik's answer with my `charMat` answer, and also adapts Henrik's answer to use "data.table" instead, for better efficiency.

Two tests were run. The first is on a similar dataset with 90K rows, and the second on one with 900K rows.

Here's the sample data:

```
biggerdata <- do.call(rbind, replicate(30000, mydata, simplify = FALSE))
biggerdata$V1 <- make.unique(biggerdata$V1)
dim(biggerdata)
# [1] 90000     4

evenBigger <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10, biggerdata, simplify = FALSE))
evenBigger$V1 <- make.unique(evenBigger$V1)
dim(evenBigger)
# [1] 900000      4
```

Here are the functions to benchmark:

```
fun1 <- function(indf) {
  cbind(indf[1], splitstackshape:::charMat(
    split.default(indf[-1], sequence(ncol(indf)-1)), fill=0))
}

library(reshape2)
fun2 <- function(indf) {
  df2 <- melt(indf, id.var = "V1")
  with(df2, table(V1, value))
}

library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT <- data.table(biggerdata)
DT2 <- data.table(evenBigger)

fun3 <- function(inDT) {
  DTL <- melt(inDT, id.vars="V1")
  dcast.data.table(DTL, V1 ~ value, fun.aggregate=length)
}
```

And the results of the benchmarking.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(biggerdata), fun2(biggerdata), fun3(DT), times = 20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#            fun1(biggerdata)  185.3652  199.8725  289.0206  308.5826  327.4185    20
#            fun2(biggerdata) 1453.8791 1605.6053 1639.8567 1758.3984 1797.2229    20
#  suppressMessages(fun3(DT))  469.8979  570.4664  586.4715  598.6229  675.2961    20

microbenchmark(fun1(evenBigger), fun2(evenBigger), fun3(DT2), times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
#              expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1(evenBigger)  1.871611  1.896351  2.071355  2.140580  2.464569     5
#  fun2(evenBigger) 26.911523 27.212910 27.363442 27.469812 27.938178     5
#         fun3(DT2)  7.103615  7.131603  7.141908  7.205006  7.218321     5
```